# Syntax Error while installing Textblob

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

I'm trying to install textblob but I always get an error. I installed nltk and spacy using pip and it worked fine but this just throws the same error over and over again.
I even tried using conda-forge but I'm getting the same error.

Please help!

Terminal SS:

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to an image of the output, but put it, with code formatting, in your question. And you should run pip from the command line, not the python interpreter.

Comment: thanks, will try that. had to link it because I got a pop up saying I need at least 10 reputation for posting pictures. sorry!

Comment: I know this might seem like a naïve thing. I've never used python. Always used R for everything but this NLP course in college is python based. Thanks for the help!